# Parse JSON returns unexpected identifier error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, zepto

I am trying to parse the following JSON string that is being returned to me but am getting an unexpected identifier error in the console.

```
"{"title":"MyApp Companion","push_hash":"ff06b5b775e45409f9ab470b64d672d0","t":"mr","alert":"Ryjjgv","n":"Foo Bar","action":"open the app at specific location","pid":"7V8meRCJaj","badge":"Increment"}"
```

I am using zepto but the method $.parseJSON() throws the error.

Comment: The console usually tells you *where* the error occurred.

Comment: Assuming the outermost quotes are not in the actual text you're parsing, that's fine. If they are, of course, that's your problem.

Comment: What's the context? How do you get the JSON?

Comment: You can use tools like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON. Your example is a valid JSON without the leading and trailing `"`

Comment: I don't have control over the string that is returned.  I need to remove first and last quotes then.

Comment: Not sure why down voted.  Question not complex enough?

Comment: Probably because you don't give enough information about where and how you get the string from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove your first and last `"` or replace with `'`

```
"{
    "title": "MyApp Companion",
    "push_hash": "ff06b5b775e45409f9ab470b64d672d0",
    "t": "mr",
    "alert": "Ryjjgv",
    "n": "Foo Bar",
    "action": "open the app at specific location",
    "pid": "7V8meRCJaj",
    "badge": "Increment"
}"
```

to

```
 '{
        "title": "MyApp Companion",
        "push_hash": "ff06b5b775e45409f9ab470b64d672d0",
        "t": "mr",
        "alert": "Ryjjgv",
        "n": "Foo Bar",
        "action": "open the app at specific location",
        "pid": "7V8meRCJaj",
        "badge": "Increment"
    }'
```

and there is on online **[TOOL jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)** , to validate your JSON

Answer (score 4):

You might have to escape quotes in your string as your string looks like this:

```
"your string("your string")"
```

It should be something like:

```
"your string(\"your string\")"
```

or
    'your string("your string")'

or:
Remove your first and last quotes

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `"` to delimit the string literal, the console is parsing the `"` inside the string as a string delimiter. Try using `'` as to delimit the literal:

```
'{"title":"MyApp Companion", ... }'
```

Alternatively, you can escape all the `"` inside the string with `\`:

```
"{\"title\":\"MyApp Companion\", ... }"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$.parseJSON('{"title":"MyApp Companion","push_hash":"ff06b5b775e45409f9ab470b64d672d0","t":"mr","alert":"Ryjjgv","n":"Foo Bar","action":"open the app at specific location","pid":"7V8meRCJaj","badge":"Increment"}')
```

Comment: Please explain the problem and the solution. Don't just write "try this".